# send headers then refresh page?

Tags: php, mysqli

I was asking earlier today about my database backup system

Here's the link: [database backup system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911408/mysqli-db-backup-with-php)

Here is the code

```
if (isset($_POST['getbackup'])) { 
        /* setcookie("backupdisable", 1, time()*60*60*24); */ 
        $db = "newsite";
        $version = "2.3.1";
        $date = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

        $final = "--   #".$version."#\n";
        $final .= "--   database backup\n";
        $final .= "--\n";
        $final .= "--   PHP version: ".phpversion()."\n";
        $final .= "--   MySQL version: ".mysqli_get_server_info($mysqli)."\n";
        $final .= "--   Date: ".date("r")."\n";

        $result = $mysqli->query("SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM ".$db);
        while ($table = $result->fetch_array()) {
        $i = 0;
        $result2 = $mysqli->query("SHOW COLUMNS FROM $table[0]");
        $z = $result2->num_rows;
        $final .= "\n--\n-- DB Export - Table structure for table `".$table[0]."`\n--\n\nCREATE TABLE `".$table[0]."` (";
        $prikey = false;
        $insert_keys = null;
        while ($row2 = $result2->fetch_array()) {
            $i++;
            $insert_keys .="`".$row2['Field']."`";
            $final .= "`".$row2['Field']."` ".$row2['Type'];
            if($row2['Null'] != "YES") { $final .= " NOT NULL"; }
            if($row2['Default']) $final .= " DEFAULT '".$row2['Default']."'";
            if($row2['Extra']) { $final .= " ".$row2['Extra']; }
            if($row2['Key'] == "PRI") { $final .= ", PRIMARY KEY  (`".$row2['Field']."`)"; $prikey = true; }
            if($i < $z){
                $final .= ", ";
                $insert_keys .=", ";
            }
            else{
                $final .= " ";
            }
        }
        if($prikey) {
            if($table[10]) $auto_inc = " AUTO_INCREMENT=".$table[10];
            else $auto_inc = " AUTO_INCREMENT=1";
        }
        else $auto_inc = "";
        $charset = explode("_", $table[14]);
        $final .= ") ENGINE=".$table[1]." DEFAULT CHARSET=".$charset[0]." COLLATE=".$table[14].$auto_inc.";\n\n--\n-- DB Export - Dumping data for table `".$table[0]."`\n--\n";

        $inhaltq = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM $table[0]");
        while($inhalt = $inhaltq->fetch_array()) {
            $final .= "\nINSERT INTO `$table[0]` (";
            $final .= $insert_keys;
            $final .= ") VALUES (";
            for($i=0;$i<$z;$i++) {

                $inhalt[$i] = str_replace("'","`", $inhalt[$i]);
                $inhalt[$i] = str_replace("\\","\\\\", $inhalt[$i]);
                $einschub = "'".$inhalt[$i]."'";
                $final .= preg_replace('/\r\n|\r|\n/', '\r\n', $einschub);
                if(($i+1)<$z) $final .= ", ";

            }
            $final .= ");";
        }
        $final .= "\n";
    }
    if($logged) {

        header("Expires: 0");
        header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
        header("Content-Description: File Transfer");
        if(is_integer(mb_strpos(strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]), "msie")) AND is_integer(mb_strpos(strtolower($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]), "win" ))) header("Content-Disposition: filename=backup-".strtolower(date("D-d-M-Y")).".sql;");
        else header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=backup-".strtolower(date("D-d-M-Y")).".sql;");
        header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
        echo $final;
        exit;
    }
    }
```

My question now is this :

The script works just fine, but now im trying to remove the submit button after you get this file so is this possible?

If i refresh the page the button will get removed but i dont know how to do so..

Because if i set a header that refreshes i can't download the file

Comment: set it on the session for example so the user can't change it and then read that session when the pages refresh and based on the value of the session print or not the button? You could also put it on the URL as a get parameter or on a cookie as unsafe alternatives

Comment: You want to prompt the user to download a file and then redirect using only HTTP headers? You cannot do this. Probably something with Javascript could work.

Comment: **Prix** i tried that, and i didn't work.. Didn't accept download did only refresh then

**miken32** javascript i tried with to but it just added the row to the file. :( 

Maybe time to realize, that the thing i want is not possible.